# bsddb3.db.DBNoSuchFileError

Tags: ethereum, wallet

I'm tryinf to recover a password for a wallet.dat and keep running into this problem:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\bitcoin2john.py", line 552, in open_wallet
    r = db.open(walletfile, "main", DB_BTREE, flags)
bsddb3.db.DBNoSuchFileError: (2, 'No such file or directory')`
```

Also, I get this after it:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\bitcoin2john.py", line 828, in <module>
    if read_wallet(json_db, filename, True, True, "", False) == -1:
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\bitcoin2john.py", line 702, in read_wallet
    db = open_wallet(walletfile, writable=FillPool)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\bitcoin2john.py", line 554, in open_wallet
    logging.error("{0}:{1}".format(e[0], e[1]))
TypeError: 'DBNoSuchFileError' object is not subscriptable`
```

Comment: Fix your file path